# Iterating through specific part of array in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

In PHP, what is the best way of iterating and passing values through the phases part of the code. The only parts that need to be iterated through is commented in the code.

```
  $schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
    'customer' => 'cus_HMDwmb8iAV0X7k',
    'start_date' => $start_date,
    'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
      'phases' => [

        // Start Iteration
        [
          'end_date' => $end_date,
          'proration_behavior' => 'none',
          'plans' => [
            [
              'price_data' => [
                'unit_amount' => $unit_amount,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product' => $stripe_product_id,
                'recurring' => [
                    'interval' => 'year',
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      // End Iteration


      ],
  ]);
}
```

Any help is appreciated and code examples are always useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using for-each loop without key

```
foreach($array['phases'] as $item) {
    echo $item['filename'];
    echo $item['filepath'];

    // to know what's in $item
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($item);
}
```

Using foreach loop with key

```
foreach($array['phases'] as $i => $item) {
    echo $item[$i]['filename'];
    echo $item[$i]['filepath'];

    // $array[$i] is same as $item
}
```

Using for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['phases']); $i++) {
    echo $array['phases'][$i]['filename'];
    echo $array['phases'][$i]['filepath'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this piece of code replace everything after //start iteration

Comment: You will need to do it recursively in order to go down into deeper array of the phases key. Especially for the "plan" key. Use the $value variable to get the value bound to the corresponding key. And iterate again with the same method when the key is "plan"